# Mimicking the "rubber band" effect from iOS in the Gallery on Android

Tags: android, gallery

I've got a Gallery class showing a bunch of images in an Android app, but since only one image is ever displayed at a time, it is difficult for the user to see when they have reached the first or last image in the gallery.  Is there a way to mimic iOS' "rubber band" effect, so that the user sees a bit of empty space when dragging the last image, and they release it, the image snaps back to the center of the view.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into easing equations

http://www.gizma.com/easing/

when releasing the screen while been dragging the last image, you can use them to smoothly animate the image back to the center of the screen.

As for the effect while dragging the last image, use a multiplication factor on the position of the image so the more your finger reaches the side of the screen, the less the image will follow its movement.